# MultiAxis HighChart: show different color

Tags: jquery, highcharts

In MultiAxis Chart(Stack & SPLine) is it possible to have different color in Stacked Column Chart?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set the `color` property of a [series](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.color) and/or a [point](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.color).

Comment: Thanks..I've already figured a way to do this..Anywayz thanks for your reply..